# While loop jumps over function in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I looked for a few hours for a solution here but I couldn't find one. Maybe someone can help me or point to a similar question?

I have a function in a while-loop. The function iterates over each line in a text file:

```
def parser():
    for line in f:
        print(line)

f = open('textfile.txt', 'r')

count = 0
while count < 7:
    parser()
    count += 1
    print(count)
```

My output is the following:

```
text file line 1
text file line 2
text file line 3

1
2
3
4
5
6
```

My initial goal was to call the function again after each +1:

```
text file line 1
text file line 2
text file line 3
1
text file line 1
text file line 2
text file line 3
2
text file line 1
text file line 2
text file line 3
3
```

... and so on.

Apologies if this is actually a duplicate and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for you usecase you need to reopen the file inside your while loop (addidionally i passed the filehander `f` as argument to the `parser` function):

```
def parser(f):
    for line in f:
        print(line.strip())  # stripping off '\n'

count = 0
while count < 7:
    with open('../var/textfile.txt', 'r') as f:
        parser(f)
    count += 1
    print(count)
```

alternatively you could also `f.seek(0)` leaving the original file open:

```
f = open('../var/textfile.txt', 'r')

count = 0
while count < 7:
    f.seek(0)
    parser(f)
    count += 1
    print(count)
```

Comment: So fast- Thanks for your help!